# Viewing a data saved in a table layout in another activity

Tags: java, android

I have saved a data in a table layout in another activity with shared preferences but when i open that activity with a button, all my data gets lost. Is there any way to View the saved data in the table layout in that other activity?

Comment: load the saved data from the shared preferences

Comment: @Johnny-wycliffe - Can you please post a few lines of your table layout code, a few lines of your activity where you are retrieving the data through Shared Preferences? This way, we can help you better, looking at the code. Thank you.